# SOQL query not working

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am trying to fetch name phone and email from contact
Not able to get the value

```
    SearchString= 'where id != null';
    if(String.isNotBlank(searchName)){
        SearchString += ' and Name Like \'%'+ searchName +'%\'';
    }else if(String.isNotBlank(searchPhone)){
        SearchString += 'and Phone =: '+  Integer.valueOf(searchPhone) ;
    }else if(String.isNotBlank(searchEmail)){
        SearchString += 'and Email Like \'%'+ searchEmail +'%\'';
    }
 contacts = Database.query('Select id, Name, Email, Salutation, Phone from Contact '+SearchString+' order by ' + sortFullExp + ' limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter);
```

Comment: Just to be sure try printing the query before you do database.query. check if the query string is correct.

Comment: I checked but there is some issue with code. It is searching Name only not phone and Email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SearchString= 'where id != null';
    if(String.isNotBlank(searchName)){
        SearchString += ' and Name Like \'%'+ searchName +'%\'';
    }
      if(String.isNotBlank(searchPhone)){
        SearchString += 'and Phone =: '+  Integer.valueOf(searchPhone) ;
    }
     if(String.isNotBlank(searchEmail)){
        SearchString += 'and Email Like \'%'+ searchEmail +'%\'';
    }
 contacts = Database.query('Select id, Name, Email, Salutation, Phone from Contact '+SearchString+' order by ' + sortFullExp + ' limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter);
```

You are doing if-else If so if your first condition satisfy then it will not check next condition. Just use normal if condition and it will solve your peoblem.

Comment: Thanks. there is problem with Phone search. for Email and Name It worked.

Comment: no need to convert into integer just use string

Comment: It is showing Error:
Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Tushar's answer. But also be aware of the risk of [SOQL injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm). A clean way to deal with that is to take advantage of dynamic SOQL's support for [simple bind variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm):

```
String nameBind = '%' + searchName + '%';
String phoneBind = searchPhone;
String emailBind = '%' + searchEmail + '%';

if (String.isNotBlank(searchName)) {
    SearchString += ' and Name Like :nameBind';
}
if (String.isNotBlank(searchPhone)) {
    SearchString += 'and Phone = :phoneBind';
}
if (String.isNotBlank(searchEmail)) {
    SearchString += 'and Email Like :emailBind';
}

contacts = Database.query(...
```

which ensures that malicious user input can't cause the query to do unexpected things.

Comment: Thanks Keith for giving Best Practices to write a code. there is problem with Phone search. for Email and Name It worked.

Comment: @Arshad Yeah I don't understand what you are doing with the phone search.

Comment: Actualy this is requirement.

Comment: @Arshad I mean I don't understand why you have the `Integer.valueOf` as that will throw an exception if non-parseable input is added. But the equivalent using bind variables would be `String phoneBind = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(searchPhone))`;.